# Showing the laravel request uri in php fpm status page

Tags: php, nginx, laravel-5, fpm

I have a php fpm 7.4 status page giving the following details :-

```
************************
pid:                  284764
state:                Idle
start time:           11/Apr/2023:21:04:09 +0200
start since:          15258
requests:             493
request duration:     274387
request method:       POST
request URI:          /index.php
content length:       192
user:                 -
script:               /home/laravel/backend/public/index.php
last request cpu:     7.29
last request memory:  2097152

************************
```

Its showing the request URI and script "/index.php" in all the processes data, how can i make php fpm status page show the user request uri (eg. /user/getDetails)

Comment: Based on https://www.php.net/manual/en/fpm.status.php, I am guessing that you probably simply - can't? _"request uri: The URI of the last served request (after webserver processing, it may always be /index.php if you use a front controller pattern redirect)."_

Comment: @CBroe In nginx access log i can see the full api request, why can't i use this variable/data in fpm status file ?

Comment: Ask whoever implemented the status page. From PHP's view, the executed script file simply _is_ the index.php here, and due to the internal rewrite, that's the "requested URL" as well. That the originally requested URL might be available somewhere in $_SERVER later on in PHP might be, but within the context of this status page, apparently is is unavailable.